# Optimizing double iteration over arrays

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, optimization

I have the following code that I wrote for a practice problem in a coding competition, but when I run it I go over time. The main culprit (I'm guessing) is the double for loop which runs in O(n^2). Is there any way to go about optimizing this code? I've tried messing with memoization, but I can't figure out how to do so.

```
for (i=n;i>0;i--){
    int index = linearSearch(seq,i,n);
    int height = bricks[index];
    for (j=0;j<n;j++){
        if (j != index){
            if (bricks[j] >= height){
                while(bricks[j]>=height){
                    bricks[j]--;
                    count++;
                }

                if(bricks[j] < 0){
                    printf("-1\n");
                    return 0;
                }

            }
        }
    }

    bricks[index] = 0;
    seq[index] = 0;
}
```

Comment: If this is working code, you should take it to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead. But **before you do that**, make sure to **write a good explanation** of your code, e.g. **document it**.

Comment: What this code is *supposed to do*?

Comment: Taking a quick look, there are many ways to optimize this code...

Comment: `while(bricks[j]>=height){bricks[j]--; count++;}` can easily be changed to `if (bricks[j]>=height){count+=heigth-bricks[j]+1;bricks[j]=height-1;}` for a start.

Comment: That is actually running in `O^3` runtime , 2 `for` loops and 1 `while` loop

Comment: when asking about a run time problem, post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the objective of the posted code snippet, but the following proposed code may help with the execution duration:

```
for ( i=n; i>0; i-- )
{
    int index  = linearSearch(seq,i,n);
    int height = bricks[index];

    for ( j=0; j<n ; j++ )
    {
        if( j != index )
        {
            if( bricks[j] >= height )
            {
                count += bricks[j] - height;
                bricks[j] -= bricks[j] - height;
            }
        }
    }

    bricks[index] = 0;
    seq[index] = 0;
}
```